# Java: how to replace space and \r in string with delimiter value?

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm

How to replace space and \r in string with delimiter value?

```
String oldDelimiter = " ";
String newDelimiter = "o";
String fileContent = "try some **random**  %!(chars)!% ##\r" +
            "or line break$@ \r" +
            ":(";
fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("[" + oldDelimiter + "]+", newDelimiter);
fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\r", newDelimiter);
```

current output: `tryosomeo**random**o%!(chars)!%o##oorolineobreak$@oo:(`

desired output: `tryosomeo**random**o%!(chars)!%o##oorolineobreak$@o:(`

Notice the extra letter `o` towards the end of the string after the `@` symbol.

Update: it should only replace with o if there is a `space` or `\r`. However, if both `space` and `\r` and next to each other, then only replace with one `o` delimiter.

Comment: Why is it extra, you have a space followed by \r, you get two "o"s.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated in post, it should only replace with `o` if there is a `space` or `\r`.

Comment: `fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("[ \r]+", "o");` i.e. use the `[ ]` *character class* you already have.

Answer (score -2):

Like Andreas said, use the "[ \r]" to replace all of the \r and " " with spaces.

```
fileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("[ \r]+", "o");
```